# PHP json_encode return null?

Tags: php, json

I have a string like below. But json_encode function return null. Because it contains like this :

*Mr. Brown (ketaptin \xc3\xa7al\xc4)*

**original :** *Mr. Brown (ketaptin çalışanı)*

How can I solve this? Which function should I use?

**My array :**

```
      [success] => 1\n    [message] => \n    
[error_code] => -1\n    
[data] => Array\n        (\n            
   [contact_subjects] => Array\n                (\n                    [0] => Array\n                        (\n                                   
   [contact_subject_id] => 1\n                            [name] => \xc3\x96neri\n                        )\n\n                    [1] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 2\n                              [name] => Soru\n                        )\n\n                    [2] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 3\n                            [name] => \xc3\x96deme Bilgisi\n                        )\n\n                    [3] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 4\n                            [name] => \xc5\x9eikayet\n                        )\n\n                    [4] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 5\n                            [name] => Ortakl\xc4\xb1k\n                        )\n\n                    [5] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 6\n                            [name] => Arad\xc4\xb1m Bulamad\xc4\xb1m\n                        )\n\n                    [6] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 7\n                            [name] => E-Kitap\n                        )\n\n                    [7] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 8\n                            [name] => Mobil Uygulamalar\n                        )\n\n                    [8] => Array\n                        (\n                            [contact_subject_id] => 9\n                            [name] => Reklam\n                        )\n\n                )\n\n            [customer_name] => Mr. Brown (ketaptin \xc3\xa7al\xc4\n            [customer_email] => hrev@hotmail.com\n        )\n\n)\n
```

Sorry for code. You can beautify it from here : http://phillihp.com/toolz/php-array-beautifier/

Comment: `json_encode` accepts an array. You are passing a string to it?

Comment: @ArminSam json_encode accepts `mixed`, meaning everything is acceptable and will be converted accordingly. See this https://3v4l.org/uOYVa

Comment: @ArminSam no. it is an array.

Comment: I try this but not working as expected https://3v4l.org/Er7BJ . reference: http://www.monkeyphysics.com/articles/read/21/decoding_byteescaped_xff_strings_in_php.html